# Powershell replace email suffix

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to write a small script that prompts users for their email address. The value of this email gets passed to a function which will replace their email suffix such as .net, .com, .edu to .org. I have the following code, but it's not replacing the suffix. Any help in this matter would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
cls
$mail = Read-Host "Please enter your email address"

Function Email ($change)
{
    $modified=$change.Replace(".{3}[A-Za-z]", ".org")
    $modified
}

Email $mail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `String.Replace` which doesn't work with regex.

Also, your regex doesn't do what you want it to do.

`.` is a special character in regex and you want to escape it. Also the `{3}` should be after the character class.

Try the below:

```
Function Email ($change)
{
    $modified=$change -replace "\.[a-zA-Z]{3}$", ".org"
    $modified
}
```

The `$` indicates end of string.

PS: If you are not validating input ( through regex match, you can as well use substring to replace to org)